# Problems of cin and scanf() on MinGW-w64

Tags: c++, mingw-w64

My MinGW-w64's version is: x86_64-8.1.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0.7z

My System's version is: Windows 10 2004

When I tried to use MinGW-w64's g++ to compile and run this source file, I ran into troubles.
this file's name is "temp.cpp"

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char player1[8] = {0}, player2[8] = {0};
    cin >> player1 >> player2;
    cout << player1 << ' ' << player2;
    return 0;
}
```

I built and ran this file in PowerShell by entered this line of codes.

```bsh
g++ -g .\temp.cpp -o .\temp.exe; .\temp.exe
```

Then I typed in the inputs.

```
Rock Scissors
```

After I pressed the enter key. I got this.

```
 Scissors
```

The first word didn't print out.

Then I use VS Code to debug the source file. I found after I entered the input, the data in `player1[0]` didn't get replaced by 'R'. Instead, it is still `0`.

Then I copy the entire mingw64 folder to another computer to try again, same thing happened again.

Then I replaced cin by using scanf().

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char player1[8] = {0}, player2[8] = {0};
    scanf("%s %s", player1, player2);
    printf("%s %s", player1, player2);
    return 0;
}
```

Same thing happened again.

Then I download the older version of MinGW-w64: x86_64-5.4.0-release-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0.7z

By using the older version, It can print out properly now.

Why?

Comment: Your arrays should be 9 characters long in order to allow 8 characters for scissors plus a null terminator or just use `std::string` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh... Your array is one-character too short for `Scissors`. You require 9-characters `8 + 1` for the *nul-terminating* character. So what happens on your stack is you have `Player1` followed by `Player2` (but since the stack grows down, `Player1` is in the memory above `Player2)`, e.g.

```
    |        Player2                |        Player1                |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
    | S | c | i | s | s | o | r | s | \0| o | c | k | \0|   |   |   |
    +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

So when you are take input for `"Scissors"` and the nul-terminating character is written for end-of-string, you overwrite the first character for `Player1` with `'\0'` causing it to appear to be an empty-string.

Lesson Learned -- *Don't Skimp on Buffer Size!* (or better yet, use `std::string`)

Declare:

```
char player1[32] = {0}, player2[32] = {0};
```

or

```
#include <string>
...
std::string player1 {}, player2 {};
```

and try again.

Comment: Or even better, use `std::string`s.

Comment: Amen to that -- solves lots of off-by-one problems `:)`

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what problem is. But I still wonder why lower version of mingw tolerated my miss. (Maybe it use different methods to store input?)

Comment: No. Writing beyond the end of your array invokes *Undefined Behavior*, so just about anything can happen. If may appear to work or it may segFault. In this case it wasn't hard to deduce what had happened. That is one of the pitfalls to using Plain Old Arrays with C++. They have the benefit of being blindingly fast, but there isn't much the compiler can do to help there. The STL containers like `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.. provide automatic memory management so they can grow as needed. Each have their place, but using the niceties that C++ provide pays dividends. Good luck coding!